# Using javax.validation validate the date must not be less than 1900-01-01

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, request, javax.validation

i have a class which is working as the request payload for my  api . I need to validate the one of my field "dateOfBirth". Using the javax.validation.past  i am checkking the date is not  future date but i also want to validate that the date must not be less than 1900-01-01 .

Is there any way using javax.validation api we can do it?

```
Class Employee{

 ----
 ---
  @Past(message="date of birth must be less than today")  
  @DateTimeFormate( pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
  private Date dateOfBirth;

  //constuctor

  //getter & setter

}
```

Comment: You can look more into *how to define custom validations and use annotations for them*.

Comment: FYI, the terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Specifically, `Instant`. The modern classes use sane counting for the year and the month, unlike the legacy classes. For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 1):

You should define custom annotation for this propose. something like bellow:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface IsAfter{
   String message() default "{message.key}";
   String current();
}
```

and also define a custom validator like this:

```
public class DateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IsAfter, LocalDate> {

String validDate;

@Override
public void initialize(IsAfter constraintAnnotation) {
    validDate = constraintAnnotation.current();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(LocalDate date, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    String[] splitDate = validDate.split("-");
    return date.isAfter(LocalDate.of(Integer.valueOf(splitDate[0]), Integer.valueOf(splitDate[1]), Integer.valueOf(splitDate[2])));
  }
}
```

and use this annotation:

```
@Past(message="date of birth must be less than today")  
@IsAfter(current = "1900-01-01")
@DateTimeFormate( pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

***note: I haven't tested this annotation!***

Answer (score 0):

The post from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258098/15541786 is great. I did it in my project and it's working. Just to avoid errors in console, add also to interface

```java
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

So, working example:

```java
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DateValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface IsAfter{
   String message() default "{message.key}";
   String current();
   Class<?>[] groups() default {};
   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```